# Split Data Frame and call subframe rows by their index

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, split

This is a very basic R programming question but I haven't found the answer anywhere, would really appreciate your help:

I split my large dataframe into 23 subframes of 4 rows in length as follows:

```
DataframeSplits <- split(Dataframe,rep(1:23,each=4))
```

Say I want to call the second subframe I can:

```
DataframeSplits[2]
```

But what if I want to call a specific row of that subframe (using index position)?

I was hoping for something like this (say I call 2nd subframe's 2nd row):

```
DataframeSplits[2][2,]
```

But that doesn't work with the error message

> `Error in DataframeSplits[2][2, ] : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: You have to use `DataframeSplits[[2]][2,]`, i.e. double parenthesis to select the second data.frame (using single paranthesis returns a list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to subset the `list` which is returned by  `split` and use it for later subsetting, you must use double parenthesis like this to get to the sub-data.frame. Then you can subset this one with single parenthesis as you already tried:

```
Dataframe <- data.frame(x = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 23), y = 1)
DataframeSplits <- split(Dataframe,rep(1:23,each=4))

DataframeSplits[[2]][2,]

#   x y
# 6 b 1
```

More info on subsetting can be found in the excellent [book by Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html).

Comment: Yes it works! I had tried double parenthesis on both ie, [[2][2,]] and on the one with the row ie [2][[2,]] but had given up, not thinking of this one! Thank you very much!